# Android 9 Pie crash (com.google.android.gms... ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, admob, android-9.0-pie

I have a Unity3D game published on Android, and it have worked well so far.
However, the Android Vitals Dashboard is now reporting a lot of crashes. Here's the detailed info:

```
By Android version: Android 9   4500    100.0%
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [Thread-360]
Unity version     : 2017.3.1p3
Device model      : Google Pixel
Device fingerprint: google/sailfish/sailfish:9/PQ2A.190305.002/5240760:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at lt.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2)
  at ls.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:1)
  at lu.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:18)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:10)
  at kx.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:7)
  at kx.run (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at ac.loadClass (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@16089081@16.0.89 (100400-239467275):4)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

My `AndroidResolverDependencies.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
  <packages>
    <package>com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0, 27.2.0[</package>
    <package>com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0, 27.2.0[</package>
    <package>com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0</package>
    <package>com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0</package>
    <package>com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 12.1.0[</package>
    <package>com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[10.2.1, 12.1.0[</package>
    <package>com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0[</package>
  </packages>
  <files>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.core.common-1.1.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.core.runtime-1.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.lifecycle.common-1.1.0.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.lifecycle.livedata-core-1.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/android.arch.lifecycle.viewmodel-1.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.customtabs-27.1.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-annotations-27.1.1.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-compat-27.1.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-core-utils-27.1.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-fragment-27.1.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-media-compat-27.1.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.android.support.support-v4-27.1.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-17.2.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-base-17.2.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-16.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-17.2.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-analytics-16.0.8.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-analytics-impl-16.0.8.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-16.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-16.2.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-17.2.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-location-16.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-16.3.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-sdk-api-16.3.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-places-placereport-16.0.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-stats-16.0.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl-16.0.8.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-16.0.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.auto.value.auto-value-annotations-1.6.jar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.firebase.firebase-common-16.1.0.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-17.1.2.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-interop-16.0.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-17.0.1.aar</file>
    <file>Assets/Plugins/Android/com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-17.6.0.aar</file>
  </files>
</dependencies>
```

```
Target API level: 28
Minimum API level: 16
```

I've seen a similar thread in [Google AdMob's discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=Es-419#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/K1HKru7RutY) suggesting to add the following to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

However:

1. I'm not sure the problem is caused by any apache-related API.
2. I'm afraid this will restrict the number of installs in my app since it will be available to a smaller audience in Google Play due to the `uses-library` declaration.

Comment: same crash here

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you try `<uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />` ?

Comment: Hi @SaadAnees. I'm afraid this will restrict the number of installs in my app since it will be available to a smaller audience in Google Play due to the uses-library declaration.

Comment: Hi @0xBFE1A8. That's the full crash information I can retrieve from Google's ANRs & crashes report.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per **[Behavior changes: apps targeting API level 28+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28)**

> **Apache HTTP client deprecation**
>
> With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client.
>   Beginning with Android 9, that library is removed from the
>   bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default. To continue using the Apache HTTP client, apps that target Android 9 and above can add the following to their `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

> **Note:** The android:required="false" attribute is required for apps that
>   have a minimum SDK of 23 or lower, because on devices with API levels
>   lower than 24, the org.apache.http.legacy library is not available.
>   (On those devices, the Apache HTTP classes are available on the
>   bootclasspath.)
>
> As an alternative to using the runtime Apache library, apps can bundle
>   their own version of the org.apache.http library in their APK. If you
>   do this, you must repackage the library (with a utility like Jar Jar)
>   to avoid class compatibility issues with the classes provided in the
>   runtime.

Comment: I just submitted an app update with the `uses-library` element included. I'll monitor the crash reports and post the results here.

Comment: Just checked the ARN & Crashes dashboard, and the issue mentioned was not present anymore. (Y)

Comment: @EduardoCoelho glagot worked. Btw can you help me?i have the same issue. I have added that lone in android manifest but its not working.

Comment: Hi @Saad. All I did was adding that line to my App Manifest to the `<application>` element. The crash mentioned in the post disappeared from the reports.